# Receiving **kwargs and unpacking arguments in the function body instead of simple arguments - why?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was looking at the `scikit-learn` implementation of `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`. Sklearn usually has high quality code so I read it from time to time to learn good practices.  But recently I found stuff like this:

```py
def train_test_split(*arrays, **options):
    """
    ...
    """
    n_arrays = len(arrays)
    if n_arrays == 0:
        raise ValueError("At least one array required as input")
    test_size = options.pop('test_size', None)
    train_size = options.pop('train_size', None)
    random_state = options.pop('random_state', None)
    stratify = options.pop('stratify', None)
    shuffle = options.pop('shuffle', True)

    if options:
        raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))

    # ...
```

I was wondering, why this kind of approach was chosen? It seems like an antipatern for me, but I assume that sklearn developers knew what they were doing, so I probably miss some point. Why not just simply:

```py
def train_test_split(*arrays, test_size=None, train_size=None, ...): 
    # ...
```

Are there any advantages of in-function unpacking?

Answer (score 2):

To condense all the answers :

1) Functions headers are less prolix needing less arguments.

2) Allows code to be easily extended without the need to redefine every invocation to the function.

3)As [johnashu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7695039/johnashu) suggested it allows to better control errors as they can be customized based on the particular entry of `**kwargs` beeing missing or wrongly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

It is to control the TypeError to give a more understandable error. I guess!

With your proposed approach the error would be:

`TypeError: train_test_split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'not_a_valid_kw'`

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer on their behalf but I believe this form of implementation allows the code to be more flexible to changes.
The library is in ongoing development process and new versions are released regularly. Some of these versions include changes to existing methods. This implementation allows supporting multiple versions without changing the signature of the method or causing it to explode with a huge amount of optional parameters.

Maybe there are other considerations that I'm not aware of but this is my guess. Hope it helps.